# How can I get all connections for selected block in jsplumb and make all connections to red

Tags: jsplumb

How can I get all connections when I select particular block from group and make all connections to be red?

I am using jsplumb to make flow chart and my requirement is that when I will click on any block so all the to and from connections needs to be turn red.